# Create dynamic proxy that implements multiple interfaces simultaneously

Tags: c#, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I can't quite figure out how to use dynamic proxy how to implement multiple interfaces at the same time. Using a third party library I have something like

```
interface ISubscribe<T> { Consume(T msg); }
```

I would like to dynamically create a class that simultaneously implements

```
ISubscribe<Foo>, ISubscribe<Bar>
```

and for each one calls `Logger.Log(msg)` (the type parameter on that is dynamic).

I can't figure out quite how to do this.

Comment: does it work if you pass the extra ones via `additionalInterfacesToProxy`?

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic Oh! ok, I clearly misread your tutorial then, yeah that seems to work.

Comment: you probably read it right. There have been some changes over the years so the tutorial may be outdated.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest that *was* another concern and I wanted to get it on the record. Want to put it as an answer for SO point$?

Comment: If I only had the time to update it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proxy creation methods have a `Type[]` parameter called `additionalInterfacesToProxy`. Pass all the extra interfaces you want to proxy through there.